# Is there a "Wrong password on lock screen" action intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, lockscreen

I'm looking for a way to get a notification if a user enters a wrong password on the Android lock screen (the system lock screen - not a lock screen in my own app). Is there an existing intent that get's fired in that situation?

Many thanks in advace.

Comment: Were you able to implement it ? I need some help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to get a notification if a user enters a wrong password on the Android lock screen (the system lock screen - not a lock screen in my own app). Is there an existing intent that get's fired in that situation?

If you have implemented a `DeviceAdminReceiver` using the device admin APIs, it will be called with [`onPasswordFailed()`](http://goo.gl/s8vUc).

Answer (score -5):

You can create your own dialog in android app to display the error message.Below is the code for that:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();
                        // Setting Dialog Title
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                        // Setting Dialog Message
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Not A User");
                        // Setting Icon to Dialog
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.inputerror);
                        // Setting OK Button
                        alertDialog.setButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                            {
                                // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                                // closed
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not A Valid User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        // Showing Alert Message
                        alertDialog.show();
                        return;
```

Comment: I'm talking about the Android lock screen. You can set a password in the Android settings. If this password is set you need to enter this password before you can do anything with that device.